# Retrieve the integer stored in (?P<topic_id>\d+)

Tags: python, django

In the `urls.py` of Django

```
#urls.py
url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic')
The second part of the expression, /(?P<topic_id>\d+)/, matches an integer between two forward slashes and stores the integer value in an argument called topic_id.
```

I try to understand it with regex

```
In [6]: re.findall(r'topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', "topics/1/")
Out[6]: ['1']
```

However, when I tried

```
In [7]: re.findall(r'topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', "topics/1/").topic_id
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'topic_id'
```

It seems that the integer is not stored in `topic_id` ,
How to understand it?

Comment: what is the idea to add `.topic_id` to `re.findall`?

Comment: Note that you don’t need to use `re` to use Django urls. Define your view as `def topic(topic_id)`, then you can simply use `topic_id` in your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your errors is not from 'topic_id', it's about `re`.

If you use `re.findall`, it returns all list matched with your regex.

So in your case, the result of `re.findall(r'topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', "topics/1/")` will be `['1']`.

So, of course, `['1'].topic_id` raise AttributeError.

If you want to get group by `'topic_id'`, do like this

```
p = re.match(r'topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', "topics/1/")
p.group('topic_id') # it returns '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
>  Return all non-overlapping
>   matches of pattern in string, as a **list of strings**.

You are trying to retrieve an attribute from a list, which that list does not have.